# how can I use npm "debug" package with es modules

Tags: node.js, debugging, import, es6-modules

this is how I used to used it in common modules.

```
const debuger=require('debug')("namespace")
```

I set an environmental variable `DEBUG="namespace"` and when i start the app, i can use the `debugger`.

However I could not figure out how to use it with `import/export` staments.

```
  import debugger from "debug" // how can i pass () here
```

Comment: `debugger` is a reserved keyword, so if you changed it to `import debug` or really anything else, it will work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do:

```
import debug from 'debug';
const logger = debug('namespace');
logger('Starting App');
```

Actually, as the npm debug module exports a function directly (`module.exports = (params) => {...`), you can give the function whatever name you like, for example:

```
import createDebugMessages from 'debug';
const debug = createDebugMessages('namespace');
debug('Starting App');
```

This way, the original syntax for debugging does not even need to be changed.